# How do I show output of powershell job in main GUI window?

Tags: multithreading, user-interface, powershell, jobs

SEE BELOW FOR UPDATE.

After looking at multiple sites and forums I've decided to post a question because I can't figure this out.

I've got a powershell script that uses WinForms to create a GUI window (shown below). The right side is to display output while the chosen checkboxes are working. It works, except the window freezes and\or becomes "not responding". I've been looking into changing things so they run inside jobs, except I can't figure out the proper syntax to have the job run, and also display what it's doing in the listbox. I understand jobs are separate powershell processes, but is there a way to display while the job is running what it's currently doing?

I'm not sure what sections of code to post because it kind of applies to the whole thing, but here's a snippet of how it currently is...

```
$handler_button1_Click= {

    $domain=$TextBox2.Text
    $user=$TextBox3.Text
    $pass=$TextBox4.Text
    $id=$TextBox1.Text

    $listBox1.Items.Clear()    

    if ($checkBox1.Checked -and !$checkBox2.Checked) { uninstall }

    if ($checkBox2.Checked -and $checkBox1.Checked) { $security -eq "y"; uninstall }

    ...

    if ($checkBox7.Checked) { $prog = "Firefox"
                              $appname = $firefox
                              $arguments = " -ms"
                              install }
}
```

Right now I have the checkboxes going to different functions that either uninstall a bunch of software using a ForEach loop, or install software. When I run the chosen boxes I'd like it to display what it's currently uninstalling or installing. It does its job, but I can't see what it's doing until it's all done, then the list refreshes and everything's there.

I've tried making the function a variable instead and then calling that with "Start-Job -ScriptBlock" in the "checkbox.checked" code above. I've tried wrapping the function inside the Start-Job command in different ways. I think I've got it to run, but I can't tell because it doesn't show me anything.

This needs to work in Windows 7.

I've attached a picture below of what the GUI looks like.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

[image]

**UPDATE:**

So I got the job to run and display output in it's PS window. Haven't figured out how to make it display output in the GUI's listbox yet though.

I'm having issues with the variables that set the working directory to the script's directory. It works fine in the main script, but throws an error that it's null or invalid when put inside a job. Here's the test script I'm using to figure this job stuff out...

Ideally what I'd like to do is have each function in the script be a job (except the main GUI function) and have each "checkbox.checked" section above start a job with it's output showing in the GUI listbox.

I copy\pasted most of the global variables from the actual script. There are a couple "write-host" lines that should be "$listbox1.items.add("")". I changed them to "write-host" so I see some output when testing.

Is there a way to have variables available to other jobs? The code below didn't work until I put the variable list inside $updates and manually typed the file path into $dir.

```
$updates = {

$global:scriptpath = $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
$global:dir = Split-Path $scriptpath
$global:logfile = "$dir\Apps\log.txt"
$global:ftppath = # REMOVED #
$global:firefox = "install_firefox.exe"
$global:chrome = "install_chrome.msi"
$global:reader = "install_reader.exe"
$global:java32 = "install_java_x32.exe"
$global:java64 = "install_java_x64.exe"
$global:flashie = "install_flash_ie.exe"
$global:flashnonie = "install_flash_nonie.exe"
$global:office = "install_o365.exe"

function updates {

$list = "Flash for IE","Flash for Other Browsers","Java 32-bit","Java 64-bit","Adobe Reader","Firefox","Chrome","Office 365"

ForEach ($prog in $list) {

    Try {

        If ($prog -eq "Flash for IE") {$appname = $flashie}
        If ($prog -eq "Flash for Other Browsers") {$appname = $flashnonie}
        If ($prog -eq "Java 32-bit") {$appname = $java32}
        If ($prog -eq "Java 64-bit") {$appname = $java64}
        If ($prog -eq "Adobe Reader") {$appname = $reader}
        If ($prog -eq "Firefox") {$appname = $firefox}
        If ($prog -eq "Chrome") {$appname = $chrome}
        If ($prog -eq "Office 365") {$appname = $office}

        $filecheck = "$dir\Apps\$appname"

        If(-not(Test-Path -path $filecheck)) {

            write-host " Downloading $($prog) Installer..."
            $File = "$dir\Apps\$appname"
            $ftp = "$ftppath/$appname"
            $webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
            $uri = New-Object System.Uri($ftp)
            $webclient.DownloadFile($uri, $File)

            "   Downloaded $($prog)" >> $logfile

        } # End If

        Else {

            $ftprequest = [System.Net.FtpWebRequest]::Create("$ftppath/$appname")
            $ftprequest.Method = [System.Net.WebRequestMethods+Ftp]::GetDateTimestamp
            $response = $ftprequest.GetResponse().StatusDescription
            $tokens = $response.Split(" ")
            $code = $tokens[0]

            $localtime = (Get-Item "$dir\Apps\$appname").LastWriteTimeUtc

            If ($code -eq 213) {

                $tokens = $tokens[1]
                $localtime = "{0:yyyyMMddHHmmss}" -f [datetime]$localtime

                If ($tokens -gt $localtime) {

                    write-host " Updating $($prog) Installer..."
                    $File = "$dir\Apps\$appname"
                    $ftp = "$ftppath/$appname"
                    $webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
                    $uri = New-Object System.Uri($ftp)
                    $webclient.DownloadFile($uri, $File)

                    "   Updated $($prog)" >> $logfile

                } # End If

                Else { $listBox1.Items.Add(" $($prog) skipped.") }

            } # End If

        } # End Else

    } # End Try

    Catch { write-host " ERROR: Couldn't update $($prog)"
            "   Error updating $($prog)" >> $logfile }

} # End ForEach

} # End Function

} # End Variable

Start-Job -Name "Updates" -ScriptBlock {updates} -InitializationScript $updates | Wait-Job | Receive-Job
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Seperate each job to one task, Then Use a timer in the background that checks each job

```
If (($JobTask1).State -eq "Running"))
   {
   $Label1.Text = "JobTask1 is Still Running"
   }
```

Another Option is to Use

```
Receive-Job $Jobs -Keep
```

And Manipulate the output to find what already done.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but I don't think that'll do what I'm looking for. Right now there is text that each function displays while it's running. For example, when the "uninstall" function is running it'll display "Uninstalling nameofprogram..." for each program it removes. Your comment seems to just confirm if the job as a whole is running or not. I'd like a way to have the text that's being generated by the function/job to be displayed in the GUI in real time. Am I asking too much? That's not meant to be sarcastic, I'm really wondering. Thanks!

Comment: When you do Receive-Job it shows any info about the process?